# Why does my Userform and modules not persist when I quit out of a spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am very new to VB. I am trying to create a userform which relies on modules, that starts upon pressing a button on the spreadsheet. I can get this working, until I exit the spreadsheet and try to load it up again and it is gone.

Why is this happening, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Always good to start with the obvious: You did save it before you closed the workbook, right?

Comment: Yes, I saved. I am new to it but I'd expect the modules and form to persist.

Comment: I've not used User Forms in Excel, so you'll have to wait for someone else to help you out, I just wanted to get the simple on out of the way. It might help if you provide a small example of your code so someone can take a look, though it does seem very odd.

Comment: Another "checking the obvious" question - you are saving as an XLSM (macro enabled) not an XLSX, right?

Comment: What exactly is missing? Is the useform not showing, or is the actual userform gone from the file. Because the latter sounds very strange. For it not showing, you need to invoke the `.show` method.